# Metro App Style: How to change the colour/remove/hide of ComboBox drop down arrow?

Tags: xaml, colors, combobox, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have this simple ComboBox:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Width="200" Background="Transparent" 
    Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Transparent" 
    UseLayoutRounding="True" SelectedIndex="0">
        <x:String>item 1</x:String>
        <x:String>item 2</x:String>
        <x:String>item 3</x:String>
    </ComboBox>    
</StackPanel>
```

I wanna change the colour of drop down arrow, is there any way to change it?
Or at least remove/hide it if possible.

Comment: Well... i found a solution, i use a TextBlock and a Popup content a ListBox with animation to make a simulator ComboBox... but not enought reputation to post the answer right away.
I will post it after 10 hours in case of anyone care about this.

Comment: I was about to say, if you just want to change the color of the dropdown arrow it's as simple as changing the Fill color of the Path that makes the Arrow in the Control Template. So you can just open up your Resource Dictionary that holds the template, find the path that is the arrow, and change the Path Fill color to whatever you like.

Comment: @Chris: oops... thanks anyway. I will try it right away!

Comment: @Chris: Unfortunately, there's no style for ComboBox in StandardStyles.xaml. I remember i was try to find it before i post this question.

Comment: I'd have to double check to be sure but I think it's with the SDKStyles. You can do a quick search of your solution for TargetType="ComboBox" I think to find it for sure, but somewhere has to be a Control Template for it. :)

Comment: I imagine that it would be easier to do using blend if you have it installed. open the xaml file in blend, select the combobox, right click it and select edit template --> edit a copy. Then change the style from there.

Comment: @Chris I tried that. But there nothing in my project. The only way to edit its style is using Blend. Just like J.B said. :3

Comment: Ah ya, I just assumed you werent using Blend, but Blend always makes working with templates way easier. Cheers

Comment: yea... this is the first time i try Blend LOL... its awesome :D

Comment: @JB you should post it as an answer and get some points mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as an answer for future reference:

you can edit the combobox style by opening the xaml file you have it defined in in Blend, right clicking the combobox, and selecting edit template --> edit a copy. From the screen that comes up you can find the appropriate values to change